# I cant create a CSS border for this content

Tags: html, css, wordpress, border

I'm using WordPress for my blog/website. On the regular pages I created borders just fine. On the blog template, I cant seem to figure out how to borders around boxes.
this is what i have so far

```
#secondary{
background-color: white;
left: 15px;
border-width: 15px;
border-color: green;
}
```

(green for visibility)
I invite you to view my live [page](http://www.overlandparkphotographer.com/contact-page/) so you can ascsess my CSS and stuff. My customized sheet is the last one titled style.css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#secondary{
    background-color: white;
    left: 15px;
    border: 15px solid green;
}
```

You are missing the `border-style` style (ie. the `solid` part), whereby it can be shortened to the above syntax for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
border: 15px solid green;
```

Here is a link if you need the complete list of border properties, http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `border-style`

```
#secondary {
  background-color: white;
  left: 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px;
  border-color: green;
}
```

Or you could use the shorthand property: `border: 15px solid green;`